# How to ignore Pycharm warning "TypedDict "" has no key '"?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am getting the error erroneously in Pycharm:

```
TypedDict "RPCResponse" has no key 'elapsed_time'
```

How can I ignore it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put

```
# noinspection PyTypedDict
```

above it.

More info on the error: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/